# How to unlimit amount of ICMP Port Unreachable responses?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, icmp

I'm trying to write a script, which would check all ports of a given address and determine on which of them UDP is listened.

To do so, I'm sending an empty packet to each port and then listen for ICMP Port Unreachable responses, which would mean that there's no UDP on the corresponding port.

While doing it, I faced with a problem: after receiving exactly 279 (each time) ICMP packets, I can't receive them more. Even on localhost.

I've Googleed it and understood only that sometimes the amount of such packets is limited. But is there a way to remove this limitation?

I've simplified my code a little to show it, here it is:

```
import socket
import struct

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP) as icmpSocket:    
    UDPPorts = set()
    for port in range(1, 2 ** 16):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
            s.sendto(b'', ('localhost', port))
        UDPPorts.add(port)

    while True:
        data, addr = icmpSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        (destPort,) = struct.unpack(">H", data[50:52])
        print(destPort)
        UDPPorts.remove(destPort)
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit). Python 3.4.3.
I would be happy to hear any helpful information: some keywords for better Googling the problem, exact solution, just explanaition of magic number 279. Everything would be interesting.

Comment: The limit is on the server you're probing, not the client where you're running your program.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, sure. But in my case the server is localhost, so, maybe there is a way to remove the limit on my machine (to make my script work at least on it)?

Comment: How will that help you in the more general case? Anyway, superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask how to change system configuration options like this.

Comment: See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html. Linux < 2.4.10 use `icmp_destunreach_rate`, >= 2.4.10 use `icmp_ratelimit` and `icmp_ratemask`.

Comment: @Barmar In no way, actually. But I'm just get interested where the limit comes from and how I could (or why I shouldn't) remove this limitation if I would build my own server, for example.

Comment: @Barmar I've seen this article. But I have no icmp module, which is described there. Or am I just doing something wrong? I've just typed `man icmp` and `icmp` in terminal, but there is no such command.

Comment: Do you see the icmp settings files in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4`?

Comment: @Barmar Oh, sorry. That's strange, but there _is_ _man_ for the command icmp, but there _isn't_ the _command_. Strange... I've tried from root too, by the way.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, saw them, but I can't write to those files. `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit` works, but `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit` gets permission denied error even with sudo.

Comment: `icmp` is not a command, section 7 is for system interfaces.

Comment: When you do `sudo command > file` the redirection is done by your normal shell before calling `sudo`, not the root process. Use `sudo bash -c 'command > file'` to do the redirection in the root process.'

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're right, it works. Perfect! Thank you very much, you explanation was really helpful (I didn't know that redirection is done by the normal shell. And also didn't know that there is a special section in man for system interfaces, not for commands)

Comment: @Barmar Ops. But the problem is still there: I've changed the limit successfully, but my script still stops after 279 packets...

Comment: You could just be filling up a kernel buffer, so it's discarding the packets because there's no room for them.

Comment: @Barmar Seems like you're right. I've started processing icmp packets in another thread and the problem was solved (this time for sure). Thank you again.

Comment: Why are you writing a tool from scratch instead of using nmap or alternatives? Those are guaranteed to work correctly.